# Unable to parse bindings.... Unexpected token '}'

Tags: javascript, electron, knockoutjs

Estoy tratando de asociar una función de un **ViewModel** al click de un botón, pero KnockOut me da un error:

> Unexpected token '}'

Lo más gracioso, es que la función no tiene código. Esta es la definición de la ventana (la parte que interese), hay otro botón que tiene asociada la función **save** del ViewModel y funciona correctamente.

```html
<button data-bind="click: delete">Eliminar</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      const ko = require("knockout");
      ...
      
      const service = new BranchService(httpRequester, "branches");
      //const branch = Branch.withDefaultValues();
      const branch = new Branch({
        id: 3,
        name: "name",
        description: "description",
        city: "city",
        address: "address"
      });
      const viewModel = new BranchViewModel(branch, service);

      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    }
</script>
```

Y esta es la definición del ViewModel. Tiene más código, pero no es relevante.

```
const ko = require("knockout");

const Branch = require("../core/models/branch");

class BranchViewModel {

  constructor(branch, branchService) {

    this._service = branchService;
    this.updating = ko.observable(false);
    this._startModel(branch);
  }

  _startModel(branch) {
    this.id = ko.observable(branch.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(branch.name);
    this.description = ko.observable(branch.description);
    this.city = ko.observable(branch.city);
    this.address = ko.observable(branch.address);
    this.isDeleted = ko.observable(branch.deleted);
    this.isNew = ko.observable(branch.isNew())
    this.canBeDeleted = ko.computed(
      function() {
        return !this.isDeleted() && !this.isNew();
      }, this);
  }

  _setModel(branch) {

    this.id(branch.id);
    this.name(branch.name);
    this.description(branch.description);
    this.city(branch.city);
    this.address(branch.address);
    this.isDeleted(branch.deleted);
    this.isNew(branch.isNew());
  }  

  save() {
    //tiene código
  }

  delete() {
    //sin código
  }
}

module.exports = BranchViewModel;
```

¿Alguien sabe por qué KnockOut me daría ese error?. Por lo que veo, el código no tiene errores.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el nombre del operador `delete`.

Se trata de una palabra reservada en Javascript y no se puede usar en KnockOut.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Palabras_Reservadas

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete